# Getting statsmodels to use heteroskedasticity corrected standard errors in coefficient t-tests

Tags: python, regression, statsmodels

I've been digging into the API of  [`statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html) and have found how to retrieve different flavors of heteroskedasticity corrected standard errors (via properties like `HC0_se`, etc.)  However, I can't quite figure out how to get the *t*-tests on the coefficients to use these corrected standard errors. Is there a way to do this in the API, or do I have to do it manually?  If the latter, can you suggest any guidance on how to do this with statsmodels results?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The `fit` method of the linear models, discrete models and GLM, take a `cov_type` and a `cov_kwds` argument for specifying robust covariance matrices. This will be attached to the results instance and used for all inference and statistics reported in the summary table.

Unfortunately, the documentation doesn't really show this yet in an appropriate way.
The auxiliary method that actually selects the sandwiches based on the options shows the options and required arguments: 
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.fit.html

For example, estimating an OLS model and using `HC3` covariance matrices can be done with

```
model_ols = OLS(...)
result = model_ols.fit(cov_type='HC3')
result.bse
result.t_test(....)
```

Some sandwiches require additional arguments, for example cluster robust standard errors, can be selected in the following way, assuming `mygroups` is an array that contains the groups labels:

```
results = OLS(...).fit(cov_type='cluster', cov_kwds={'groups': mygroups}
results.bse
...
```

Some robust covariance matrices make additional assumptions about the data without checking. For example heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation robust standard errors or Newey-West, `HAC`, standard errors assume a sequential time series structure. Some panel data robust standard errors also assume stacking of the time series by individuals.

A separate option `use_t` is available to specify whether the t and F or the normal and chisquare distributions should be used by default for Wald tests and confidence intervals.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but is the call to `result.bse` needed for the robust residuals from `HC*` to be used in the *t*-tests, and to appear in `result.resid`?  Or is `model_ols.fit(cov_type='HC3')` all I need?

Comment: No, you don't need to call anything else after `fit`. `bse` and `t_test` were just two examples where the specified `cov_type` is used. The robust sandwich covariance is stored in `cov_params_default` and used everywhere where we need the covariance of the parameter estimates. A simple way to verify it is to create two results instances with different `cov_types` and check that the results that depend on the covariance matrix are different, e.g. in `summary()`.