# Getting (new) t-stats after calculating a robust covariance matrix

Tags: covariance, statsmodels, robust

I calculated a simple OLS Regression like this:  `model = sm.OLS(y,X)`, `results = model.fit()`

I found that my residuals are heteroskedastic. That's why I calculated a robust covariance matrix in order to get robust standard errors and calculate new t-stats according to those robust standard errors. The robust covariance-matrix I calculated by using:

`robust_cov = sm.stats.sandwich_covariance.cov_white_simple(results, use_correction=True)`

From which I could extract robust standard errors:

`robust_se = sm.stats.sandwich_covariance.se_cov(robust_cov)`

Now I would like to use the `robust_se` to calculate new t-stats but I have no clue how to do that.

I have stumbled upon a question which I think should actually explain well enough how to solve my problem: [Getting statsmodels to use heteroskedasticity corrected standard errors in coefficient t-tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553838/getting-statsmodels-to-use-heteroskedasticity-corrected-standard-errors-in-coeff)

Unfortunately, I don't quite understand the explanation. Respectively, I tried to do `results = model_ols.fit(cov_type='HC0')` (and HC1, HC2, HC3) as mentioned in the question above. But that leaves me with exactly the same standard erros and t-stats as in the original model.

Can anyone give me a hint what I do wrong?

Comment: Hi - did you ever find the answer to this question?