# account for non-homogeneity of variance (heteroskedasticity) in statsmodels ANOVA

Tags: python-3.x, statsmodels, anova, variance

Greeting to the community.

I am using `statsmodels` in order to conduct ANOVA and one of the prerequisites of ANOVA is that the independent variables should have equal variances.

I am using the levene test through `scipy` in order to check for the presence of the effect (i apply the test in each of the groups of all the independent variables).

I found that `statsmodels` have an option that is supposed to account for that effect (or this is just my understanding). What I do now is that if the test is negative (p>0.05, heteroskedasticity present), I am using the following implementation:

```py
model = smf.ols(formula=eq, data=data).fit(cov_type='HC3')
```

in order to make [the fit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553838/getting-statsmodels-to-use-heteroskedasticity-corrected-standard-errors-in-coeff) and then anova with:

```py
anova_table = sm.stats.anova_lm(model, typ=2, robust='HC3')
```

My question is if my understanding is correct on what this option does and if yes if I can trust ANOVA results when using it. The documentation is practically non-existent.

thanks in advance

Comment: please edit your question as it is a little bit confusing. You will have one dependent variable for ANOVA.

Comment: edited the question

Comment: There're many reasons why heteroskedasticity exists and many ways to test. You may want to use WLS https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/wls.html